# Issue using reusable cell in collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, xcode10, uicollectionreusableview

I am adding a collection view programmatically. And every time I try to return a cell, I keep getting this error:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3698.140/UICollectionView.m:2022`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'`

But I am using the correct identifier to dequeue it. I register it in viewDidLoad. I couldn't find anything online.

Registration:

```
   view.backgroundColor = .white
        reports = readData()
        filterOptionsView.delegate = self
        filterOptionsView.dataSource = self
        filterOptionsView.register(OptionsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: OptionsCell.identifier)
        if let layout = filterOptionsView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }
```

Dequeuing:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if(collectionView == filterOptionsView) {
        let optionsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OptionsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! OptionsCell

        return optionsCell.configureCell(option: tags[indexPath.row], selected: selectedTag == tags[indexPath.row])
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Show please how you register your cell.

Comment: And your **else statement**, you just returning `UICollectionViewCell()`

Comment: It never reaches the else part. It crashes on the first call. I have updated the question and added the full error statement.

Comment: @ParthTamane You need to register your cell somewhere. It should be done in viewDidLoad.

Comment: The problem was, I was returning a new cell in configureCell method, instead of just setting the cell up. Changing that fixed this issue.